# Plotting equation of error function

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, evaluation

I want plot $W$ vs $t$

```
eqn= t^3 + (4 - 8/Sqrt[\[Pi]]) w^2 + (3 w^4)/8 + (2 E^(w^2/t) \[Pi] w^2 (-2 t + w^2) Erfc[w/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[t])]^2)/t ==1/8 t (96 + 56 t + 11 w^2) + (E^(w^2/(2 t)) w (-64 w^2 + Sqrt[\[Pi]] (t (-160 + 7 t) - 8 (-8 + t) w^2 + 3 w^4)) Erfc[w/(
Sqrt[2] Sqrt[t])])/(8 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[t])
```

I tried Plot using: `solns= Solve[eqn, w] // Normal`
and obtain all solutions of $W$ as the function of $t$ and then plot with

```
Plot[Evaluate[w /. solns], {t, 0, 3},PlotRange -> {{0.001, 3}, {-3, 3}}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

But I not getting. I try using `CountorPlot`, but the plot is horrible.
Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 2):

Because it doesn't seem to be possible to solve for $w(t)$, what you could do to obtain the plot of $w(t)$ is by numerically solving for $w$ for different values of $t$ with `FindRoot`. The results can then be plotted with `ListLinePlot`.

```
numberOfPoints = 300;
wStart = 1;
ts = Rest @ Subdivide[0, 3, numberOfPoints];
ws = Last @* Last /@ Table[
  FindRoot[Evaluate[eqn /. t -> n], {w, wStart}],
  {n, ts}
];
ListLinePlot[Transpose @ {ws, ts}]
```

(Note that `Rest` is to exclude the case in which $t = 0$.)

[image: ListLinePlot]

## Update

At first I ignored the `FindRoot::lstol` messages, which I shouldn't have. One way of checking if each pair of numerically-obtained $(w, t)$ actually satisfies `eqn` is by looking at the difference between its left and right sides. The difference should be close to zero.

Trying this:

```
numberOfPoints = 5;
wStart = 1;
ts = Rest @ Subdivide[0, 3, numberOfPoints];
ws = Last @* Last /@ Table[
  FindRoot[Evaluate[eqn /. t -> n], {w, wStart}],
  {n, ts}
];
points = Transpose @ {ws, ts};
diff = Subtract @@ List @@ eqn;
diff /. {w -> First @ #, t -> Last @ #} & /@ points
```

we get:

```
{-4.72339, -14.1116, -26.7086, -41.0978, -55.888}
```

As they're not relatively close to zero, the numerical solutions are bad. One way of addressing this is by giving `FindRoot` a better `wStart`.

To find it, we could explore the plot of the difference at some values of `t` to visually identify `w` at which `diff` is zero. It appears that

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[diff /. t -> n, {n, ts}]], {w, -3, 10}, PlotRange -> {-600, 50}]
```

[image: Plot]

which signifies that `wStart` should be somewhere near `-2` for $t \in (0, 3]$. Let's try `wStart = -3`:

```
numberOfPoints = 5;
wStart = -3;
ts = Rest @ Subdivide[0, 3, numberOfPoints];
ws = Last @* Last /@ Table[
  FindRoot[Evaluate[eqn /. t -> n], {w, wStart}],
  {n, ts}
];
points = Transpose @ {ws, ts};
diff = Subtract @@ List @@ eqn;
diff /. {w -> First @ #, t -> Last @ #} & /@ points
```

from which we get

```
{2.226*10^-13, 4.9738*10^-14, 4.36984*10^-13, 7.31859*10^-13, -4.54747*10^-13}
```

which are all close to zero, so this `wStart` is good. Now, back to the code at the beginning, with the better `wStart` (and note that because `t` shouldn't be too close to zero, I let `ts` start at `11/100` rather than `0`):

```
numberOfPoints = 300;
wStart = -3;
ts = Subdivide[11/100, 3, numberOfPoints];
ws = Last @* Last /@ Table[
  FindRoot[Evaluate[eqn /. t -> n], {w, wStart}],
  {n, ts}
];
ListLinePlot[Transpose @ {ws, ts}]
```

No more `FindRoot::lstol` messages.

[image: ListLinePlot]

Comment: Hi @Talki, thanks. I have a problem with your code because I have an alert in the plot, of the kind:
************************
$FindRoot:$ The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.
********************
$General:$ Further output of FindRoot::lstol will be suppressed during this calculation.
************************

And the plot blue is the same, but without the frame.

Comment: @will.al Those warnings come from `FindRoot` for some values of `t` and `wStart`, and basically mean that `w` solved may not be correct. You might want to adjust `wStart` or perhaps change the method of `FindRoot` until the warnings disappear, but I wouldn’t find them concerning, because the plot is smooth. As to the frame, it’s just the matter of formatting the plot; consult the documentation on relevant options of `ListLinePlot`.

Comment: @will.al Gosh, I look into the issue and the numerical solutions are really bad... Updating the answer right now...

Comment: @will.al Done! What we can learn from this is that it is important to find a good starting point for `FindRoot` somehow first.

Comment: Thank you so much @Taiki.

Answer (score 2):

A way:

```
eqn = t^3 + (4 - 8/Sqrt[\[Pi]]) w^2 + (3 w^4)/
8 + (2 E^(w^2/t) \[Pi] w^2 (-2 t + w^2) Erfc[
    w/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[t])]^2)/
t - (1/8 t (96 + 56 t + 
    11 w^2) + (E^(w^2/(2 t)) w (-64 w^2 + 
      Sqrt[\[Pi]] (t (-160 + 7 t) - 8 (-8 + t) w^2 + 3 w^4)) Erfc[
     w/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[t])])/(8 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[t])) // Simplify

ContourPlot[eqn == 0, {t, 1/10, 3}, {w, -3, 3}, FrameLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

In near point `t=0`

```
ContourPlot[eqn == 0, {t, 1/10000, 3}, {w, -3, 3}, FrameLabel -> Automatic,
PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 4, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

Real part of `eqn`:

```
 Show[{ContourPlot[(eqn // Re) == 0, {t, -2, -1/100}, {w, -3, 3}, 
 FrameLabel -> Automatic, WorkingPrecision -> 20], 
 ContourPlot[(eqn // Re) == 0, {t, 1/100, 3}, {w, -3, 3}, 
 FrameLabel -> Automatic, WorkingPrecision -> 20]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Mariusk Iwaniuk.